# On Component Re-rendering, input file with value not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, react-hooks, controlled-component

I'm using controlled Input with type file in React Component. If I selected one file in input component and toggling show/hide behavior of main component. On Component re-renders input is not working and throwing below error:

`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.`

```
const [filePath, setPath] = useState('');
<input
    key={"a"}
    id={"1"}
    name={"file input"}
    type="file"
    value={filePath}
    multiple
    onChange={(event) =>
      setPath(event.target.value)
    }
  />
```

Comment: Could you include the code causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are referring wrong thing for getting filename

you should use `event.target.files[0]`

try using

```
onChange={(event) => setPath(event.target.files[0].name)}
```

and if you are setting default value to empty string to your state variable `const [filePath, setPath] = useState('');`

then just this should work too

```
value={filePath}
```

Also you might need to consider using `defaultValue` prop

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax problem

Change

```
value={filePath | ''}
```

to

```
value={filePath || ''}
```